# Websphere CWWIM6004E

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to start an application in Websphere 8, and keep on getting the following error.
From the message, it means we are missing the `bindPassword`, but we never have to define in WAS 6.1

Currently we are using Standalone LDAP registry. Does anyone have any idea where I should start looking to fix this error?

```
UserManagemen E com.ibm.ws.wim.management.UserManagementProcess handleNo
tification CWWIM6004E Initialization of the dynamic reload manager failed.
                                 com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.MissingInitPropertyException: CWWIM0004E  The initialization property 'bindPassword' is missing from the configuration.
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.initializeEnvironmentProperties(LdapConnection.java:194
7)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.initializeServers(LdapConnection.java:1904)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection.initialize(LdapConnection.java:1832)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapAdapter.initialize(LdapAdapter.java:235)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:610)
        at com.ibm.ws.wim.RepositoryManager.<init>(RepositoryManager.java:131)
```

Comment: This error is a `VMM` error, can you please verify if you are using Standalone LDAP or a Single LDAP under Federated Repositories. Also, does this happend when you start the application or when you start the server ?

Comment: Thanks, currently we are using Standalone LDAP server, not under federated repositories. I got the error when I start the server.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to ".... never have to define in WAS 6.1"

The requirement for a LDAP bind password is enforced by the LDAP server, this is not a WAS requirement

If in fact you didn't define it in WAS v6.1, the LDAP server in use for WAS V6.1 didn't require it.

Based on the error, you've either changed LDAP servers or the LDAP server configuration has changed (or both)

As mentioned in the other post, you can troubleshoot this using a tool like ldapsearch

The technote at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21470063 discusses obtaining "must gather" and troubleshooting these types of issues (refer to the "collecting data manually" section)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the ldapsearch as described, and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your ldap connection to the ldap server
User IBM WebSphere Console, Security settings, LDAP and take note about the LDAP connection settings.
Use a tool like ldapsearch in order to check the connection via shell command line.
It is possible that these bind password is not correct.
If you are using un Novell eDirectory Server you must take special attention in the bind user creation ( field password )